# Snowflakes SQL replace multiple words

Tags: sql, string, replace, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table named CLIENT_REPORT with CAMPAIGN_NAME and CAMPAIGN_ID that looks like this:

```
CAMPAIGN_ID | CAMPAIGN_NAME
 IO000001   | MOBILE_WEB_PREROLL_ROGERS_IO00001
 IO000002   | MOBILE_WEB_NONEGUARANTEE_ROGERS_IO00002
      ....
```

I want to remove everything else beside the client name and their CAMPAIGN_ID, so in this case I want

```
CAMPAIGN_NAME
ROGERS_IO00001
ROGERS_IO00002
```

I have created a look up table

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE REPLACEMENT_TABLE (
   string_pattern VARCHAR(16),
   string_replacement VARCHAR(16)
)
INSERT INTO REPLACEMENT_TABLE (
   string_pattern,
   string_replacement
)
VALUES
   ('MOBILE_', ''),
   ('WEB_', ''),
   ('PREROLL_', ''),
   ('NONEGUARANTEE_', ''),
   ('XP_', ''),
   ('MA_', ''),
....
;
```

The tables are in the same DB but different Schemas, and I don't know how to incorporate the two.
CLIENT_REPORT is in the SALES schema and REPLACEMENT_TABLE table is in the UTILITY schema

this is what I attempted so far..

```
SELECT REPLACE("CAMPAIGN_NAME",
    "MY_DB"."UTILITY"."REPLACEMENT_TABLE".string_pattern,
    "MY_DB"."UTILITY"."REPLACEMENT_TABLE".string_replacement) 
FROM "MY_DB"."SALES"."CLIENT_REPORT";

SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 43 invalid identifier 'MY_DB.UTILITY.REPLACEMENT_TABLE'
```

Comment: I think the first step would be a `JOIN` to get both tables data in the query

Comment: @FelipeHoffa what do they join on though? could you please elaborate? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no doubt many ways you could approach this.  One method is simply to reconstruct the string that you want:

```
select cr.*,
       rt.string_pattern || '_' || cr.campaign_id
from client_report cr join
     replacement_table rt
     on cr.campaign_name like '%' || rt.string_pattern || '%';
```

Answer (score 1):

Tested this and it's working as long as the REPLACEMENT_TABLE doesn't get too large (16 MB in the object_construct)

```
create or replace function replace_from_list(S string, R array)
returns string
language javascript strict immutable
as
$$
    for (var i = 0; i < R.length; i++) {
        S = S.replace(R[i].STRING_PATTERN, R[i].STRING_REPLACEMENT);
    }
    return S;
$$;

select CAMPAIGN_ID, replace_from_list(CAMPAIGN_NAME, (select array_agg(object_construct(*)) from REPLACEMENT_TABLE)) as CAMPAIGN_NAME from CLIENT_REPORT;
```